# Javascript Switch Case statement Issue

Tags: javascript, switch-statement, case

Hoping someone can help me here. The first three out of the four cases work just fine. the default case line returns a blank, instead of a date 6 months later. Even if I remove the default and put in the actual case ('Sem') I still don't get the date of 6 months later returned. Can anyone tell what I may be doing wrong? Thank you

```js
var d = new Date();
switch ('[Relationship-rel_performance_frequency]'.substring(0,3))
{
 case 'Mon':
         ((d.getMonth()+2)+'/'+d.getDate()+'/'+(d.getFullYear()+0));
         break;
 case 'Qua':
         ((d.getMonth()+4)+'/'+d.getDate()+'/'+(d.getFullYear()+0)); 
         break;
 case 'Ann':
         ((d.getMonth()+1)+'/'+d.getDate()+'/'+(d.getFullYear()+1)); 
         break;
 default:
         ((d.getMonth()+7)+'/'+d.getDate()+'/'+(d.getFullYear()+0));
         break;
}
```

Thank you

Mark

Comment: `'[Relationship-rel_performance_frequency]'.substring(0,3)` is always `[Re`

Comment: The posted code makes very little sense. The code in each `case` does not do anything.

Comment: you are not saving the code in the cases anywhere...

Comment: case 'Mon': return ...; case 'Qua' return ...; return is missing

Comment: You also have problems with your math. In case "Mon", you are adding 1 to the month, but what if the month is December, or the Day is the 31st of January, You'll end up with the 31st of February. Etc.

Comment: Hi. The above code is only a snippet of a larger code. Let me provide some more details.  [Relationship-rel_performance_frequency] is pulling in a Text Value of Annually, Quarterly, and Monthly, SemiAnnually. Based on the string, the code will determine the date and populate it in the future. The first three cases work, but no matter what I do for SemiAnnually, or even if I use default for that scenrio, it doesn't seem to calculate the date.

Comment: Your code works fine for me (copied it into the console and ran it). There are issues with it though like how you aren't storing or returning the result of each of the case statements. Also, they don't handle cases where the month ends up greater than 12 (Current result of execution is `"14/2/2018"`).

Comment: you can put a `console` in `default` part to make sure it really goes into, and check why it doesn't go into or why it doesn't work properly.

Comment: Try to make sample code and console output your statements in switch. Your code as it is does nothing.

Comment: So where are the returns? Did you add console.log lines to figure out why??

Comment: Thank you everyone for the help. The issue is in the number of months going beyond 12. Back to rewriting the formula.

Comment: You probably want to find a javascript Date library. There are lots of things to consider when adding dates. Since not all months have the same number of days, just adding 1 to the month can cause you to have an invalid date. You've already found the month number going beyond 12. There is the Leap year and leap century to worry about too. Although I guess you probably don't worry about leap century too much, unless you think your code is going to be around 82 years.